# How do I nextline after a dot in a set of next lined words in .txt file

Tags: python

I have a problem with my code. I have a text file and inside of this text file is a thousand of tabbed/next lined words which came from a sentence. My problem is I want to revert the words inside of this text file and make it a sentence again.

I have thought of a way which is making a for loop statement and if it hits the dot `.` then it will store the sentence inside the list.

```
with('test','r') as f:
    text = f.open()

sentence = []
sentences = []
for words in text:
    if words != "."
       sentence.append(words)
    elif words == "."
       sentence.append(words)
       sentences.append(sentence)
       sentence = []

#Sample output
#[['This', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'sentence', '.'],
#['This', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'sentence', '.']],
```

```
#This is the text file
This
is
a
sentence
.
This
is
the
second
sentence
.
This
is
thr
third
sentence
.
```

The code kinda works but it's a little bit complicated. I'm finding a much shorter and not so complicated idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should provide a sample input and a sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Read from file, split into lines by period, split each line by any whitespace, rejoin line with single spaces, throw the period back at the end of the sentence.

```
sentences = [' '.join(x.split()) + '.' for x in open('test','r').read().split('.')]
```

Comment: This did the trick. I have edited it and it seems like it didn't need the ' . ' before the for loop and the ' . ' inside the split only just the ' ' will do. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split()`.

For example:

```
text = 'First sentence. Second sentence. This is the third sentence. '
text.split('. ')[:-1]
>>> ['First sentence', 'Second sentence', 'This is the third sentence']
```

If you want to include the *.* you have to do it like this:

```
text = 'First sentence. Second sentence. This is the third sentence. '
split_text =  [e+'.' for e in text.split('. ')][:-1]
split_text
>>> ['First sentence.', 'Second sentence.', 'This is the third sentence.']
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one liner for the same, Let me know if need more help:

```
sentences = open('test','r').read().split('\.')
```

Comment: The problem here is that you will not include the dot itself.